# Richtextbox values showing in single line

Tags: sql-server, silverlight-4.0, richtextbox

In SQL server I have one column with "text" datatype when we run the query I'm getting some character like box when i copy that data to clipboard that box character turns to new line.My issues is I'm binding that column to C1richtextbox so its showing in single line.

You can see the box below:

[image]

How can i get that value in next line same as whatever in database when we copied to clipboard?

Comment: Are you really using the `text` datatype in SQL Server? I'd strongly suggest changing to `varchar(MAX)`. `text` has been deprecated for a long time (I can't recall if it was in 2008 or 2005). As for your question, we can't see your text, so this question is going to be difficult to answer. What is a "box character"? Like this? `□`. Is it a `CHAR(10)` or a `CHAR(13)`, perhaps both?

Comment: Yes even i changed the datatype like Convert(varchar(MAX), table_notes_log.internal) when run that query im getting box character as shown in above image

Comment: That image looks like a single line Combo Box... And `CONVERT` doesn't stop that your data is still stored as `text`. It's not related to the problem at hand, but you shoud, just stop using the `text` datatype.

Comment: Could you just help me how to replace that square box to next line in Sql Server???

Comment: Without knowing what that square box actually is, no. Also, like I said, that image shows a combo box; normally combo boxes don't support multi-line displays.